# configure Centos with NTP

Tags: linux, centos, ntp

I would like to configure my servers to use NTP.
I would like them all to use GMT time zone.
I would like to use public NTP server
how do I do it?

Comment: If you do this please also explain to your users how to use the `TZ` environment variable...

Comment: It's not necessary to have your server keep time in UTC to use NTP correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To configure the timezone link `/etc/localtime` to the file in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` which matches the timezone that you want

```
date 
Mon May  9 09:18:22 BST 2011

sudo mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.old
sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime

date
Mon May  9 08:19:42 GMT 2011
```

To install ntp (if it's not already)

```
sudo yum install ntp
sudo chkconfig ntpd on
sudo service ntpd start
```

EDIT:

As far as I'm aware the default `/etc/ntp.conf` will contain all the public servers you require. If however you need to you can add the following `server` configurations

```
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org
server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org
server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org
```

You can use the [ntpq](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ntpq) command to see if it's working.

```
/usr/sbin/ntpq -p

     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*time.nist.gov   .ACTS.           1 u  397 1024  357  147.843    1.518   4.840
```

the offset value tells you how how far out of sync you are

Comment: don't I need to configure ntpd.conf for publie NTP servers? how do I check if ntpd works?

Comment: thank you but when I do it and check "date" I get UTC and not GMT:  mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.old
 ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime
 date
Mon May  9 14:34:02 UTC 2011

Comment: I only see the UTC variant if there is no /etc/localtime - check that it exists and is correctly linked to /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT

Comment: this is what I see:/etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT
 cat /etc/localtime
TZif2
GMT0

Comment: On my CentOS 5.5 & 5.6 systems it all works as described above. Have you got a TZ environment vatiable set e.g. TZ=UTC ? If you don't then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I know. on all my other machines it works the same way (GMT). I only have an issue with that machine. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

To set the timezone to GMT use:

> $ sudo rm /etc/localtime
>
> $ sudo ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/GMT /etc/localtime

---

To install NTP use:

> $ sudo yum -y install ntp

And make it active with:

> $ sudo chkconfig ntpd on
>
> $ sudo service ntpd start

Comment: Is London really GMT?  I was under the impression that they went to "Summer Time" every year (similar to Daylight Savings Time here in the US).

Comment: @mdpc: your right, I copied it from a server I configured a couple of days before, and forgot to change it to GMT. I edited the answer, so it should be correct now.